# Is this the best way to get the time it takes to run an async task?

Tags: c#, async-await

I want to find out how long it takes to execute my async tasks, so that I can improve on the execution time.

Please look at the test method and advise. Test background: I want to find out the user account manager from Active Directory given the sAMACcountName.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetManagerAsync_TestMethod()
{
    // connect to the Active Directory
    var serviceUsers = new User(@"LDAP://XXXXXXXXX", @"USER", "PASSWORD");

    // get the time before the start of operation
    var sTime = DateTime.Now;

    // perform the task
    var task = await serviceUsers.GetManagerAsync(@"sAMAccountName");

    // get the time after the operation
    var eTime = DateTime.Now;

    // get the time span between the start and end time
    TimeSpan taskRunTime = eTime - sTime;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Operation took {0} seconds", taskRunTime.TotalSeconds);

    Assert.IsNotNull(task);
 }
```

Comment: Use a StopWatch http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Related reading: [Eric Lippert on common C# benchmarking mistakes](http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one). You are making (at least) mistake #5.

Comment: From @Heinzi's link: "`DateTime.Now` is only slightly better than that grandfather clock: it only ticks every few milliseconds. Worse, the rate at which it ticks is not fixed from machine to machine."

Comment: @dcastro thank you for the highlight, just wanted something quick to highlight my dilemma.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Updated link to [Eric Lippert on common C# benchmarking mistakes.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508055053/http://tech.pro:80/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one). Thanks @Heinzi for the original comment.

Comment: @ErdoganKurtur: Eric migrated those articles to his new blog, here's the up-to-date link: https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var task = await serviceUsers.GetManagerAsync(@"sAMAccountName");
stopwatch.Stop();

var elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Not only is it more semantically correct, it's also way more accurate:

> If the installed hardware and operating system support a high-resolution performance counter, then the Stopwatch class uses that counter to measure elapsed time. Otherwise, the Stopwatch class uses the system timer to measure elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you @dcastro, its better than my option and it has improved my CodeLens method maintainability by 2 points.